# Double Glazed Window - missing plastic corner frame insert

Tags: windows, replacement, seal, rubber

Is there any way I can track down this missing piece? It goes at the bottom corner of the window; on the side where the windows meet each other.
It fell out of one of my windows. I don't know what the brand of the window is - but there appears to be a Superman like `S` logo on the rubber.
I'm in Portugal; but any thoughts on what key words to google most welcome; so far I'm not getting any leads.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The piece in the picture does not appear to be rubber (looks plastic/vinyl) and does not appear to be a "sealant piece". It looks more like a corner frame insert for the sash. Probably proprietary and not available to purchase, even if you knew the manufacturer...

Comment: Thanks for your points; question modified accordingly. I fear you may be correct regarding proprietary and not available to purchase ... might have to whip out the 3d printer for this one.